# How to ragged partition a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, wolfram-mathematica, partition

Is there a built-in Python function such that with

```
vals=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

then `foo(vals,2)` gives

> ```
> [[1,2],[3,4],[5]]
> ```

I am looking for the behaviour that Wolfram Language gives with

```
Partition[Range@5, UpTo@2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}}
> ```

Comment: @IsharaMadhawa That question is definitely related (I did not find it as I was searching for partition). Notable difference is ragged partitions in this case and even partitions in the linked case.

Comment: @das-g Please post an answer.

Comment: @Edmund It doesn't matter ragged or not, the question I mentioned was what you're looking for. It is applicable for both cases. check my answer.

Comment: @das-g I think `sliced` from `more-intertools` is the answer I need. Unfortunately that is not one of answers in the question this is marked as a duplicate of.  The best I can do is up vote your comment.  Thanks.

Comment: @Edmund, You could also add the answer to the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks) yourself. Having all answers on one post rather than scattered is one of SO's features.

Comment: @jpp That question has 57 answers on equally sized partitions.  Is it reasonable to expect someone to; think that a question on evenly sized partitions has an answer for unevenly sized partitions, and then expect the person to search through 58 answers to find it?  I don't think that is a reasonable expectation.

Comment: We should re-open this question, as although https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks may cover unevenly sized / "ragged" partitions, too, this question is more precises by explicitly asking about them.

Comment: @Edmund, The definition of a duplicate isn't "same question" but "same answer" - in this case, the top answer is identical to the one I gave.

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Comment: @das-g The question is reopened. May you add `sliced()` as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is built into neither the Python language itself nor its standard library, but might be what you are looking for functionality-wise:

Install the third-party-library [more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools) (not to be confused with the `itertools` module, which *is* part of the Python standard library), e.g. with

```
pipenv install 'more-itertools >= 2.4'
```

Then you can use the [function `sliced()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.sliced) it provides:

```
from more_itertools import sliced

vals = [1,2,3,4,5]
slices = list(sliced(vals, 2))

print(slices)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

If the iterable isn't sliceable, you can use [`chunked()` from the same library](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) instead of sliced.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension with list indexing / slicing:

```
vals = [1,2,3,4,5]

def foo(v, j=2):
    return [v[i:i+j] for i in range(0, len(v), j)]

print(foo(vals, 2))

[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]

print(foo(vals, 3))

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 'n' is the subgroup size. 'l' is the list

```
def groups(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]
```